# XSLT - Select only one set of data

Tags: xslt

Need some help: I want to only pull back the results for a specific ItemId, so if i wanted the only data for ItemId how could I adapt the template below?

I've tried for about 2 hours without any luck...

Here is a sample of my XML:

Comment: What does "data for ItemId" mean? Which node you want to get by `@ItemId`, exactly?

Comment: Why did you edit out the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Xslt only brings the item with ItemId value equal to 2075. 
Notice I added `[ItemInfo/PeriodAttendanceInfo/ItemId=2075]`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_2"/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="dvt_2">
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/ArrayOfPeriodAttendanceGroup/PeriodAttendanceGroup[ItemInfo/PeriodAttendanceInfo/ItemId=2075]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_2.rowContents">
      <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="dvt_2.rowContents">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
      <xsl:sort select="ItemInfo/PeriodAttendanceInfo" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="dvt_2.rowContentsView"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="dvt_2.rowContentsView">

    <xsl:variable name="subjectName" select="ItemInfo/PeriodAttendanceInfo/ItemText"/>
    <tr class="{$subjectName}">
      <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:value-of select="ItemInfo/PeriodAttendanceInfo/ItemText"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:variable name="subjectID" select="ItemInfo/PeriodAttendanceInfo/ItemId"/>
        <a class="leftAlign" href="../Departments/{$subjectID}">

          <xsl:value-of select="ItemInfo/PeriodAttendanceInfo/ItemText"/>

        </a>
      </xsl:element>
      <td>
        <p class="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Total"/>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Present"/>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Late"/>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="UnauthorisedAbsence"/>
        </p>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="dvt_1.empty">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_ViewEmptyText">There is no timetable view for today</xsl:variable>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="ms-vb">
          <xsl:value-of select="$dvt_ViewEmptyText"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```